# ARM: Is writing/reading from int atomic?

Tags: c, arm, atomic

On ARM architecture, unfortunately I don't know exactly what chip it is, is a 32 bit int read/write atomic?

Is there any sort of guarantees about reads/writes to basic types?

Comment: If that `int` is suitably aligned (to 4 bytes), I guess that, like on most 32 bits processors, the write is somehow atomic. However, the real question is the memory model (notably in multi-core situations : cache coherency, etc.).

Comment: Even in if there is no cache coherency, the read/write to main memory would still be atomic (but delayed)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes memory model is a good point, but I only have on ARM cpu with one core.

Comment: Yes, it is atomic (except perhaps in a packed struct). See my full answer, including for all other data types, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52785864/4561887.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be atomic, EXCEPT if that int is stored on a non-aligned address.

Comment: How does one find out if it's stored on a non-aligned address?  I didn't do any special aligning.

Comment: Check whether its address mod 4 is 0. Although if you didn't do anything weird (type-punning, etc.), then the compiler's going to make it aligned.

Comment: Actually some ARM processors like the Cortex-M3 support unaligned access in HW, so even an unaligned read/write is atomic.  The access may span multiple bus cycles to memory, but there is no opportunity for another instruction to jump inbetween, so it is atomic to the programmer.

Comment: Last I checked ARM does not support unaligned access. In any case this question is tagged C and unaligned access is illegal C (undefined behavior).

Comment: @TonyTheLion: The only ways an `int` can come into existence in C all necessitate that it's on an aligned address. The only way it wouldn't be is if you illegally try to access some memory that's not an `int` as if it were.

Comment: @TJD, you're ignoring shared memory between processors/cores. Another processor might change the data while the current processor is connecting the parts.

Comment: @TonyTheLion What about packed structures?